# Ubuntu 18.04 Unlocked screen without password

Tags: security, hdmi, lock-screen

Last night I closed my (Dell Inspiron 15 3000) while Ubuntu was running.
This morning I open the lid and was faced with the login / password screen which is normal and expected.
Next I plugin in my USB hub that has mouse and keyboard plugged in. All was normal (still on lock screen).

Then I plugged in my monitor by plugging in HDMI cable.
At that point the screen display went from the laptop screen to my desktop monitor and went right into Ubuntu without keyboard or mouse ever being touched. In other words it seemed to bypass security.
Any Ideas?

**UPDATE**

I did a little more testing.
I wanted to see if the above issue would repeat.

I unplugged the USB Hub.
I unplugged HDMI cable and desktop then appeared on laptop as expected.
I closed lid for a minute or so.
Opened lid and to my desktop appeared without without access. ( not on lock screen as expected).
I was surprised!. I am fairly certain laptop went to sleep but this model does not have any led to let you know.

I thought I will manually lock the screen and then close the lid and try it that way.
To my **surprise** the screen **would not lock** using keyboard on laptop or using lock screen from menu. It was as if the command was completely ignored.

Okay then, I shutdown laptop. Plugged in monitor and USB hub.
Started up laptop and everything was as expected for the initial login.

Next I tried repeating the initial process.
From a logged in desktop I unpluged USB hub and then HDMI cable.
Laptop screen now shows desktop.
I closed lid and waited a minute.
Open lid and was met with issue, NO login screen straight to Desktop with full access.
Also lock screen is failing at this point from keyboard and menu.

At this point I am getting the impression that hot swapping HDMI is somehow silently crashing lock screen.
Without hot swapping HDMI I never get this issue. I have been using this laptop for about a year now.

Comment: Is it possible that you were on TTY7 and you were logged in TTY1 and accidentally switched back to TTY1?

Comment: @AmourSpirit errrr the way you describe it can't have happened. could you provide some more details?

Comment: I don't know what else to say, I took my laptop to the library yesterday. Without power supply. Came home last night plugged laptop back in without opening lid. This morning did exactly as I posted above with the result I mentioned.